# Is $(\frac{1}{ x}\frac{d}{d x})^k(\frac{x}{\sinh x})$ always a bounded function?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Consider $f_{k}(x)=(\frac{1}{ x}\frac{d}{d x})^k(\frac{x}{\sinh x})$, $x>0$,  $k=0,1,2,\cdots.$ Then, Is $f_{k}(x)$ always a bounded function?

The only thing one need to care is the behavior when $x$ is near $0$, and prove it's bounded. I try the case $k=1,2,$ and I think it's true for general k as well. Does anyone know how to prove this or disprove it?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a_j x^{2j}$, then 
$$ \dfrac{1}{x} \dfrac{d}{dx} g(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty 2 j a_j x^{2j-2}$$

Comment: Thanks, the function $f_{k}(x)$ is actually real analytic when x is near $0$, so it must be bounded,isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

One has 
$${\sinh x\over x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{x^{2k}\over(2k+1)!}= s(x^2)\ ,$$
where $$s:\quad z\mapsto s(z):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty{z^k\over (2k+1)!}$$ is an entire function with $s(0)=1$. Therefore its reciprocal
$$\sigma(z):={1\over s(z)}$$
is well defined and analytic in a neighborhood $U$ of $z=0$. It follows that
$$f_0(x)={x\over\sinh x}={1\over s(x^2)}=\sigma(x^2)\tag{1}$$
for all $x$ in a suitable neighborhood $U'$ of $x=0$. I claim that
$$f_k(x)=2^k\>\sigma^{(k)}(x^2)\tag{2}$$ for all $k\geq0$ and all $x\in U'$.

*Proof.* The case $k=0$ is $(1)$. If $(2)$ holds for $k$ then one computes
$$f_{k+1}(x)={1\over x}{d\over dx}f_k(x)={1\over x}2^k\>\sigma^{(k+1)}(x^2)\cdot 2x=2^{k+1}\>\sigma^{(k+1)}(x^2)\ .$$